# Monotouch: how to prompt the user to configure iCloud at launch?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, icloud

I successfully implemented iCloud support in my Monotouch app following the iCloud example on the Xamarin website:

[Introduction to iCloud](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_iCloud)

But reading the documentation I've found that I'm also required to ask the user if he wants to use it or not, and (if he accepts) I need to open the iCloud settings panel.

Here is the sentence from Apple Docs:

> "If iCloud is not configured, ask users if they want to configure it
>   (and, preferably, transfer them to Launch Settings if they want to
>   configure iCloud)."

What are the best practices to ask the user the first time he launches the app if he wants to use iCloud? And how to launch the iPhone settings panel for iCloud? Is it sufficient to show the user my app settings panel, with an iCloud On/Off switch?

Thanks in advance.